# can't find substring in regex

Tags: python, regex

I can't figure out how to get "any text" from the string `any text [monkey bars][fancy swing][1002](special)`

after a lot of trying I've made `(.*)[\(*]|[\[*]` but it doesn't seem to work very well

I'm using the python regex engine

Comment: Can you show us what code you're currently running?

Comment: If your actual scenario is similar to this one a regex might be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regexp `^[^[]*` to match everything up to the first `[`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
import re

str1 = "any text [monkey bars][fancy swing]"

re1 = re.compile("(.*) \[.*")
m = re1.match(str1)

print(m.group(1))
```

That will print `any text`

You can also do something like this:

```
import re

str1 = "any text [monkey bars][fancy swing]"

re1 = re.compile("(.*) \[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]")
m = re1.match(str1)

print(m.groups())
```

This will print `('any text', 'monkey bars', 'fancy swing')`